# Prolog type hierarchy in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types, prolog

I'm currently working towards building a Prolog in Haskell using Parsec. Though my knowledge of Haskell is modest at best, the promise of Parsec and a strong type system were more than enough to draw me in.

I've began by mapping out the language in terms of a type hierarchy progressing from literal primitives (Atoms, Variables) to the abstract (Rule, Head, Clause).

```
infix 6 :-
data Program   = Program [ProExp]
data ProExp    = ProExp Fact | Rule
data Fact      = Fact Head
data Rule      = Rule Head Body
data Body      = Clauses [Clause] | Link Char
data Head      = Head Clause
data Clause    = Clause Predicate Terms
data Goals     = Goals [Predicates]
data Predicate = Predicate String
data Terms     = Terms [Term]
data Term      = Constant String
               | Variable String
```

The terms used follow Clocksin's *Clause and Effect*.

How can I improve this type system in a way that's conducive to use of Parsec? Please share any criticism of my design choices to this end.

Comment: looks fine but this is not a good question for an FAQ site like this - it seems a bit opinionated

Comment: I would write `type Program = [ProExp]`, `type Fact = Head`, `type Rule = (Head, Body)` and so on. Making everything `data` can cause a lot of boilerplate. The difference between `type` and `data` is that `type` introduces a synonym, while `data` introduces a new data type, so e.g. you can apply `map` to a `Program` when `Program` is a `type`, but not  a `data`. And even if you really want a new data type, most of your `data`s should be replaced with `newtype`s.

Comment: I am not certain if this is too useful. After all, you only have terms, nothing else. A "rule" is a term with the functor `:-/2`, for example. Terms are easy enough to model. What you need however is to define the semantics of evaluating a query. For example, what are the semantics of `,(Term1, Term2)`? And what do you do with this comma, after all? It is a control predicate, but it is also part of the term syntax.

Comment: @Carsten How do you suggest I frame my question to elicit more objective answers?

Comment: Just to be clear on this: A Prolog program can be seen as pure data. The structure of a classical Prolog program is very simple: it is an unordered collection of predicates; each predicate is an ordered collection of clauses. Every clause is a (nested) term. This is it. On top of this you have to add the proof strategy, if you want to be able to evaluate queries. As it stands in your question, you have already put way too much (unnecessary) detail into the data model, maybe due to trying to adhere too closely to the terminology. Just my $0.02.

Comment: @DavidShaked ... I did not intend this to be critique - your question is fine - it just does not fit the indent of SO (in my opinion) - this seems to be more like an question on architecture or even a code review request

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Overall the approach is perfectly fine. In fact Haskell and other functional languages are well-known for being a good fit for this. Some caveats:

1. Some of these types seem to be not really be useful, e.g. if I defined `Terms` at all it would be as a type synonym `type Terms = [Term]` instead of `data`, and I would prefer just using `[Term]`.
2. For single-field single-constructor types `newtype` is commonly used instead of `data`, unless you actually need the extra laziness.
3. "Clause" in Prolog refers to what you call `ProExp`: either a fact or a rule. As in 1, I wouldn't make `Fact` and `Rule` separate types, just constructors of `Clause`:

   ```
   data Clause = Fact Head | Rule Head Body
   ```

   (maybe even just `data Clause = Fact { head :: Callable } | Rule { head :: Callable, body :: [Callable] }`, but `Head` may well be useful when actually implementing Prolog). Or remove `Fact` completely, since it's basically just a `Rule` with an empty body, once you get around to implementing things.
4. In general, you probably want to refresh your memory instead of working "to the best of your recollection".

Comment: I am not too sure about this whole thing, including the fact vs. rule distinction. After all, you only have terms. A "rule" is then the term `:-/2`, for example, `:-(foo(X), bar(X))`. Whether a term is a fact or a clause of a predicate depends on whether it is evaluated or not.